# Racket (Scheme) with quotes inside lists

Tags: list, scheme, eval, racket

I have a problem with Racket (Scheme) and the procedure "Eval".

To check "eval" in Dr.Racket, we can type in the interpreter, e.g.,

```
(eval '(+ 5 2))
```

If we work with lists, we can have,

```
(eval '(append '(a) '(b)))
```

That returns,

```
'(a b)
```

Until here all is fine,
but I want to do something like:

```
(define x_list '(append a))
(define y_list '(b c))

(eval (list (car x_list) (cdr x_list) (list (car y_list))))
```

That obviously doesn't work, because there are not quotes 
in front of the lists, i.e. what is doing is,

```
(eval '(append (a) (b)))
```

My question is, there is any way to put the quotes in
front of the lists to make this working??

```
(eval (list (car x_list) (cdr x_list) (list (car y_list))))
```

Comment: I'll chime in with the usual caution that `eval` is usually the wrong thing to use. See [this blog post](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(eval (list (car x_list) `',(cdr x_list) `',(list (car y_list))))
=> '(a b)
```

The trick was using quasiquoting, check the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html) for more details.

Comment: It might be nice to show the more verbose way with `(list 'quote ...)`, just to show that there's no "magic" here, just syntactic sugar